# Java Gson encode with Object is not working

Tags: java, gson

The following code is working

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class DataObject<T> {

    private int data1 = 100;
    private String data2 = "hello";
DataObject child;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
  {
    add("String 1");
    add("String 2");
    add("String 3");
      }
    };
    private Map<String, DataObject> data=null;

    public DataObject(int i){
        this.data1 = i;
        this.data = new HashMap<String, DataObject>();
    }

    //getter and setter methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "DataObject [data1=" + data1 + ", data2=" + data2 + ", list="
    + list + "]";
    }
    public Map<String, DataObject> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void addData(final String key, DataObject value, Class<T> t) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }
}

public class test {



    /**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    DataObject obj = new DataObject(12);
    obj.child = new DataObject(25);
    obj.addData("myOtherData", new DataObject(32), DataObject.class);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
    }

}
```

output:

```
{"data1":12,"data2":"hello","child":{"data1":25,"data2":"hello","list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"],"data":{}},"list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"],"data":{"myOtherData":{"data1":32,"data2":"hello","list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"],"data":{}}}}
```

but I actually need to make the work with a generic

```
Map<String, Object> data
```

So this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class DataObject<T> {

    private int data1 = 100;
    private String data2 = "hello";
DataObject child;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
  {
    add("String 1");
    add("String 2");
    add("String 3");
      }
    };
    private Map<String, Object> data=null;

    public DataObject(int i){
        this.data1 = i;
        this.data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    //getter and setter methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "DataObject [data1=" + data1 + ", data2=" + data2 + ", list="
    + list + "]";
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void addData(final String key, Object value, Class<T> t) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }
}

public class test {



    /**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    DataObject obj = new DataObject(12);
    obj.child = new DataObject(25);
    obj.addData("myOtherData", new DataObject(32), DataObject.class);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
    }

}
```

which is not working:
output:

```
{"data1":12,"data2":"hello","child":{"data1":25,"data2":"hello","list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"],"data":{}},"list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"],"data":{"myOtherData":{}}}
```

myOtherData object is missing, because Gson cannot work with general Object

That's why I started putting the class as third argument of the addData method, I would need to put

```
Map<String, <T>> data;
```

I don't know the way to declare a configurable type in the map

thanks for anyone who will make that work

---

edit : it's almost working like that

I'm getting the error 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: DataObject cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at DataObject.addData(test.java:41)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class DataObject<T> {

    private int data1 = 100;
    private String data2 = "hello";
DataObject child;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
  {
    add("String 1");
    add("String 2");
    add("String 3");
      }
    };
    private Map<String, Class<T>> data=null;

    public DataObject(int i){
        this.data1 = i;
        this.data = new HashMap<String, Class<T>>();
    }

    //getter and setter methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "DataObject [data1=" + data1 + ", data2=" + data2 + ", list="
    + list + "]";
    }
    public Map<String, Class<T>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void addData(final String key, Object value, Class<T> t) {
        data.put(key, (Class<T>) value);
    }
}

public class test {



    /**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DataObject obj = new DataObject(12);
    obj.child = new DataObject(25);
    obj.addData("myOtherData", new DataObject(32), DataObject.class);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
 Remove the class parameter of the addData() method, it is not needed. Simply type the value with `T` directly and type `data`with `Map<String, T>`. Initialize the map with: `this.data = new HashMap<String, T>();`

---

This works for me (I typed your Map value with T and removed the unncesary Class parameter of addData). But your code actually works without those modifications. I ran it on my machine and I had the same output as the one you mark as "working".

What is a little bit weird, is your typing of DataObject. It is confusing because you have also an inside member (child) which is of the same class. I don't know if it should be of the same type `DataObject<T>` or not. You should try to type properly your generics as much as possible. If you are unable to do so, it may be the sign of some incorrect use of generics.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class DataObject<T> {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("String 1");
            add("String 2");
            add("String 3");
        }
    };
    private int data1 = 100;
    private String data2 = "hello";
    DataObject child;
    private Map<String, T> data = null;

    public DataObject(int i) {
        this.data1 = i;
        this.data = new HashMap<String, T>();
    }

    // getter and setter methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataObject [data1=" + data1 + ", data2=" + data2 + ", list=" + list + "]";
    }

    public Map<String, T> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void addData(final String key, T value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }
}

public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataObject obj = new DataObject(12);
        obj.child = new DataObject(25);
        obj.addData("myOtherData", new DataObject(32));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(obj));
    }

}
```

Comment: what Java Compiler version are you using I have the following error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Expecting parameterized type, got class DataObject.
 Are you missing the use of TypeToken idiom?
 See http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener
 at com.google.gson.TypeInfoFactory.getActualType(TypeInfoFactory.java:105)

Comment: @ca11111 Java 6, but I don't see any reason for this not to work with Java 5 or Java 7.

Comment: @ca11111 The error you have is not related to the Java compiler. I use GSon 2.1. Which one are you using?